# Is $\frac{1}{\tanh(x+ia)} = P\frac{1}{\tanh(x)} -\pi\delta(x)$ true?

Tags: distribution-theory

There is a well-known identity, which holds in a distribution sense:
$$\frac{1}{x+ia} = P\frac 1x -\pi\delta(x).$$
Here, $\lim_{a\to 0^+}$ is understood, $P\frac 1x$ denotes the Cauchy principal value distribution.

Since $\tanh x \approx x$ for small $x$, one may suspect that
$$\frac{1}{\tanh(x+ia)} = P\frac{1}{\tanh(x)} -\pi\delta(x).$$
Is this identity true?

I think this is true. Considering the difference between the second and the first identity, enough to show that:
$$\frac{1}{\tanh(x+ia)} - \frac{1}{x+ia} = P\frac{1}{\tanh x}-P\frac 1x.$$
However, the function $1/\tanh z - 1/z$ is regular near $z=0$. Hence, we can safely take $a\to 0$ and remove the $P$ symbol. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct.